# Text not passing through command line arguments in shell script in FreeBSD

Tags: shell, unix, freebsd

In my main function of shell script, there's a function being called

`send_report "{1}" "{2}"`

The send_report function has a send_mail function which looks like

```
Send_Mail "${sub}" "${recip}" "`cat MSG_TEXT.txt`"
```

Now the send_mail function has 3 arguments being passed, the third argument being the body, which here is the content of MSG_TEXT.txt which carries the right content I've checked.

```
if test "$3X" = "X"
 then {
echo "$NAME- `date`" >> ${rootpath}Mail_MSG.txt
}
else {
cat $3 >> ${rootpath}Mail_MSG.txt
}
fi

mail -s "`cat ${rootpath}Mail_MSG.txt`" $MAILTO
```

I'm getting the mail, but the body is coming the value of

```
"$NAME- `date`"
```

which means , the text of $3 arg is not read and satisfying the first condition of If. So I wanted to know if I'm passing the command line args wrongly at these function calls ??

note -- Running FreeBSD

Comment: Several things... `cat $3` is likely an error waiting to happen when `$3` contains anything except a filename that is accessible. `"{1}"` and `"{2}"` are literal strings containing exactly those characters, so if that's really what your `send_report` call looks like, it's probably not right. Instead of `if test "$3X" = "X"`, try `if [ -z "$3" ]` to check for an empty string.

Comment: @twalberg ok so I'll remove the double quotes on `{1}` and `{2}` in `send_report` ...I will also use `-z` flag on `$3` ...but what confuses me here is `MSG_TEXT.txt` has the content in it, so when I use it from the `Send_Mail` function why does it echo the name and date in mail body, instead of the content of MSG_TEXT.txt ....is the If condition failing ?

Comment: I don't think there's enough here to know what's happening. Try putting `set -x` somewhere early in your script, then you can trace each command as it's run and check to see if things are running as you expect.

Comment: ok, will do that and let you know, thanks

Comment: I did `ksh -x mail_script.sh` I can see in the `send_report` function no args are passed,even without double quotes. @twalberg

Comment: My point about the `send_report` call wasn't the double quotes, but that I suspected that you meant to say `send_report "${1}" "${2}"` with the dollar signs to reference positional arguments. Not literal strings `"{1}"` and `"{2}"`...

Comment: yes, they are positional args, not the literal string

Comment: On FreeBSD it is advised to use `/bin/sh` for shell scripts because it is part of the FreeBSD base system. The Korn shell (`ksh`) is a port that might not be available. For examples of shell-scripting, see e.g. `/etc/rc.subr`.